# Spring and MariaDB - Select committed data while another transaction deleting/inserting

Tags: mysql, spring, mariadb

I have a batch job which will regularly delete all data of a table A and insert new fresh data within an atomic transaction.
At the same time, I have a 24x7 online API for selecting records from table A.
How can I set the isolation level of the batch job transaction to allow the 24x7 select to get old committed data during each batch job run instead of waiting for lock & timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## RENAME TABLE

[RENAME TABLE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rename-table/) provides the ability to swap tables atomicly.

So populate new table contents:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE new_data LIKE data;
INSERT INTO new_data ...
```

Rename:

```
RENAME TABLE data TO old_data, new_data to data
```

Cleanup:

```
DROP TABLE old_data
```

Assumptions:

No API query is going to hold the table open for a significant time.

A limited table level grant can be performed so that the user can create/rename/drop these two tables:

```
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.new_data TO user;
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.old_data TO user;
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.data TO user;
```

ref: [grant table privileges](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#table-privileges), [rename table privileges](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rename-table/#privileges).

Alternately this could be in a procedure with [SQL SECURITY DEFINER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/):

```
CREATE USER rotateuser@localhost ACCOUNT LOCK;
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.new_data TO rotateuser@localhost;
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.old_data TO rotateuser@localhost;
GRANT CREATE,DROP ON db.data TO rotateuser@localhost;
```

The procedures:

```
CREATE DEFINER=rotateuser@localhost PROCEDURE new_data SQL SECURITY DEFINER
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE new_data LIKE data;

CREATE DEFINER=rotateuser@localhost PROCEDURE switch_data SQL SECURITY DEFINER
RENAME TABLE data TO old_data, new_data to data;
```

Then give ordinary user execute privileges on these two procedures:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON db.new_data TO user;
GRANT EXECUTE ON db.switch_data TO user;
```

Then just [CALL new_data()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/call/) and `CALL switch_data()`. The `OR REPLACE` handles the need to `DROP old_data`, but can be done if needed.

## Transaction

As transactional tables allow view of the table before the current transaction:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM data;
INSERT INTO data ...;
COMMIT;
```

Any isolation view will work with this.

Comment: Thanks @danblack. May I know if there is any other solution without creating temporary table? Because my batch job DB user ID is not allowed to create table.